# Google Maps APIでpolyline のmouseover時,event.latLngの緯度情報が異常

Tags: javascript, google-maps

下記コードで地図を航空写真にした場合、真上で無く斜め45度になるZoomから経度は問題無いが緯度が大きく北にずれて困っています。尚航空写真以外ROADMAP等の場合は異常となりません。

```
google.maps.event.addListener(polyline, 'mouseover', function(event) {
   console.log(event.latLng.lat() + ", " + event.latLng.lng());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

自己レスです。
航空写真が斜め45度表示に成らない様にmap.setTilt(0);を追加することで解決しました。
Maps JavaScript API マニュアルに「45° 画像を無効にするには、Map オブジェクトの setTilt(0) を呼び出します。」の記述がありました。